# Excel Changing Cell Value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm struggling to solve a problem with my Excel document so I'm hoping that someone more experienced can help?

I have a cell that updates my account balance after each trade is recorded.
I then have in my ROW for each trade the % P&L based on the account balance at the time the row is completed - the problem is that the account balance cell is dynamic so as that changes then so does the individual trade P&L % (win/loss) in each row? I have tried to use the $h$1 cell lock but this is not working?

I started with a £5k balance so what I need to achieve is the % P or L for that particular trade at the time the trade was closed; currently it keeps changing as the account balance changes which is no use for recording purposes?

Can any one help? Thank

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Can you give a screenshot or a short example XLS uploaded somewhere? That would make it easier to help.

Comment: You’re probably going to need to use VBA for this.  P.S. It’s often helpful to specify what version of Excel you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but is not 100% secure. I suggets using dedicated accounting software for this.

In excel you are limited to making a calculation only update when you manually tell it to update.

From the top menu select `Formulas` then under `Calculation Options` select `Manual`...

[image]

*You need to be aware that this will NOT prevent the calculation from happening again but it will not happen until someone tells it to calculate again.*

Comment: Many thanks Kevin - I'll give that a try! Is there a way of deleting the formula once it has activated and replacing the cell value with the result? That way once calculated it wouldn't change?

Comment: That is very simple, simply copy and "paste value" on top of the cell. You can right click to get the option to "paste value"